# Adding an extra string to std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, exception

I'd like to have a custom exception that has embedded contextual information, including strings, and a formatted `what()`.

e.g.:

```cpp
struct MyError : public std::runtime_error {
  MyError(std::size_t line, std::size_t column, std::string expected, std::string found) 
    : std::runtime_error(FormatPrettyMessage(...)), line(line), column(column), expected(expected), found(found) {}
  MyError(const MyError&) = default;
  MyError& operator =(const MyError&) = default;
  ~MyError() = default;

  size_t line;
  size_t column;
  std::string expected; // these are
  std::string found;    // problematic
};
```

[Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644735/should-i-declare-the-copy-constructor-of-my-exceptions-noexcept), though, say an exception should have a `noexcept` copy constructor, because throwing might involve implicit copying.

The above can't have a `noexcept` copy constructor, as copying a string can throw `std::badalloc`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) hints that standard libraries use a copy-on-write string to avoid this ([libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/stdexcept) indeed uses an internal COW string implementation).

But how should a layperson idiomatically add a string member to their custom exception? Trying to serialize my data and stuff it into the `runtime_error` message, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410767/c-custom-exception-throw-in-constructor) recommends, feels hacky and forces the exception handling code to parse and reformat the `what()` output. But throwing a whole custom string into my small project just to make an exception pretty feels excessive.

Comment: `std::exception` and derived classes aren't required to store a `std::string`.   To avoid exceptions when copying them, they will typically use a `char *` that is initialised appropriately (e.g. that points at a statically defined array, or a non-static member of a (implementation-specific) fixed length).  You might consider those as options. Generally speaking, however, using an exception to carry extra data around is a bad idea (both philosophically and practically). Rather than trying to bundle extra data (strings) into an exception, find another way to communicate such information.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Can you point me to any good resources about why bundling like this is bad, and what is the right way to pass that type of information?

Answer (score 1):

You can *move* the strings instead of *copy* them, especially since you are passing them into your constructor **by value** to begin with, so they have already been copied by the caller before your constructor is even entered. The `std::string` move constructor is marked `noexcept`.

```cpp
MyError(std::size_t line, std::size_t column, std::string expected, std::string found) 
    : std::runtime_error(FormatPrettyMessage(...)), line(line), column(column), expected(std::move(expected)), found(std::move(found)) {}
```

Comment: Are noncopyable extensions of `std::runtime_error` allowed, given all the rules around its copy constructor?

Comment: @parktomatomi I don’t know what rules you are referring to, but adding `std::string` members to any class, `std::runtime_error` or otherwise, are not noncopyable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was operating under the assumption that my exception must have a noexcept copy constructor, and was asking how to meet that requirement with a string member. I edited the question to try to make more sense.